# How to get value of selected radio button returning the value

Tags: javascript

I've tried before with the examples on the others post, but none of them works?

This is the code.

```js
function sumvalnotset(modelbtn) {
    var model;
    for (var i = 0; i < modelbtn.length; i++) {
        if(modelbtn[i].checked) {
            model = modelbtn[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    var p = document.getElementById("sumvalnotset");
    p.innerHTML = "the value is " + model
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Select:</p>
    <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="22,8" onclick="sumvalnotset('genoptradio1')">example1
    <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="29,6" onclick="sumvalnotset('genoptradio1')">example2
    <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="34,2" onclick="sumvalnotset('genoptradio1')">example3
    <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="31,2" onclick="sumvalnotset('genoptradio1')">example4
  </div>
  <p id="sumvalnotset">the value is 0</p>
</body>
```

Comment: You're passing a String to the function, and then you're checking if each of the characters in that String is checked. It appears you need to pass a NodeList.

Comment: Instead of passing 'genoptradio1' you should pass this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify it by passing in `this`. From the event you can the get the `defaultValue` or just `value`

```js
function sumvalnotset(e) {
    var model = e.defaultValue;
    var p = document.getElementById("sumvalnotset");
    p.innerHTML = "the value is " + model
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Select:</p>
    <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="22,8" onclick="sumvalnotset(this)">example1
    <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="29,6" onclick="sumvalnotset(this)">example2
    <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="34,2" onclick="sumvalnotset(this)">example3
    <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="31,2" onclick="sumvalnotset(this)">example4
  </div>
  <p id="sumvalnotset">the value is 0</p>
</body>
```

Comment: And if i want to use the result to create an outside variable(global) that i can use for another function or expression inside my script; how can i do that?

Comment: Create a variable at whatever scope you want, outside, then assign the result to it. So, outside you have `var model;`, then in the function you have `model = e.value` any function that is inside where you declared the variable now has access to it

Comment: i did as you told me bu it doesn't work...i've setted outside the function the var model; and to try i create another <p> and in my script a docum....innerHTML = model to write inside my p the result.

Comment: Try this, it works as you expect I think `var model; /* setting outside the function */

function sumvalnotset(e) {
    model = e.defaultValue;
    var p = document.getElementById("sumvalnotset");
    p.innerHTML = "the value is " + model
}`

Comment: if i want to use var model outside my function it returns undefined

Comment: I took a look, but don't know why, even if the function seems right also for me it doesn't work...i'm starting to think that my pc has a problem, it's strange...it returns only "the value is 0"

Comment: Create a fiddle with your code and I can take a look if you like. It's nothing to do with your pc.

Answer (score 1):

Try it by handing in the button's value as `this` and then in your function access the value as follows:

```js
    function sumvalnotset(modelbtn){
       // here you access the actual value of the clicked radio button
       const value = modelbtn.value;     
       alert(value); 
    }
```

```html
<body>
        <div>
          <p>Select:</p>
              <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="22,8" onclick="sumvalnotset(this);">example1
              <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="29,6" onclick="sumvalnotset(this);">example2
              <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="34,2" onclick="sumvalnotset(this);">example3
              <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="31,2" onclick="sumvalnotset(this);">example4
        </div>
        <p id="sumvalnotset">the value is 0</p>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code.

```js
function sumvalnotset(modelbtn) {
  var p = document.getElementById("sumvalnotset");
  p.innerHTML = "the value is " + modelbtn.value
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Select:</p>
    <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="22,8" onclick="sumvalnotset(this);">example1
    <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="29,6" onclick="sumvalnotset(this);">example2
    <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="34,2" onclick="sumvalnotset(this);">example3
    <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="31,2" onclick="sumvalnotset(this);">example4
  </div>
  <p id="sumvalnotset">the value is 0</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `onclick` to every `<input>` and loop through all the inputs. I would suggest you to use `:checked` to determine which radio is checked.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.modelbtn').forEach(input => {
 input.addEventListener('click',sumvalnotset)
})
function sumvalnotset(){
 //it will get the radio input with class '.modelbtn' which is checked
 let model = document.querySelector('.modelbtn:checked');
 //checks if any radio is checked
 if(model){
  document.getElementById('sumvalnotset').innerHTML = "the value is " + model.value
 }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Select:</p>
  <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="22,8">example1
  <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="29,6">example2
  <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="34,2">example3
  <input class="modelbtn" name="genoptradio1" type="radio" value="31,2">example4
</div>
<p id="sumvalnotset">the value is 0</p>
```